# How to know if the mouse is still over a definite object

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript

I have a bar and a button on the stage.  When the mouse is over the button, the bar height increases gradually to its final size (for example from 0 px to 200 px) gradually in about 4 seconds

When the mouse is out of the box, the bar should decrease :D

The problem is:

If the mouse moves out of the box during that 4 seconds, the bar still increases to the max height.
How can I match both cases simultaneously?

Comment: Please make up your mind whether your question is about ActionScript or CSS (I'm guessing AS since you mention the stage), then tag it accordingly - using the tags field, not the title field.

Comment: you should post your code

Comment: How are you changing the bar height?  One of Greensock's tweening libraries?  With Transitions?  With the [Animate](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/effects/Animate.html#includeExamplesSummary) class?  With a Timer function?  The answer depends on which technique you're using.

Answer (score 1):

You will want to use a MouseEvent for this.  Your object probably has a MouseOver and MouseOut property.  MouseOver will allow you to do whatever you want when you hover over the object.  MouseOut will allow you to do whatever you want when you stop hovering over the item.

Pseudocode:

```
<mx:Object id="myObj" height="100" width="100" mouseOver="{mouseOnObject()}" mouseOut="{mouseOffObject()}"/>

public function mouseOnObject() {
    myObj.height = 110;
    myObj.width = 110;
}

public function mouseOffObject() {
    myObj.height = 100;
    myObj.width = 100;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

put an if statement inside a loop checking if the mouse in inside the area(to increase the size of the box) and an else statement (which will run if the if statement isn't true)to shrink the size of the box

Answer (score 0):

Use the event `MouseEvent.ROLL_OUT` on the box to stop it.